# Jquery clone row and its all elements with different id

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

HTML Table whose 2nd row which I want to clone is

```
<table id="tblDoc" class="doc-Table">
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Document Description</label></td>
    <td>
        <label>Custom</label></td>
    <td>
        <label>File Type</label></td>
    <td>
        <label>Ref</label></td>
    <td>
        <label>Document</label></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="uploadrow_0">
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDocumentDescription_0" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="txtCustomFileName_0" type="text" class="upload-TextBoxes" /></td>
    <td>
        <select id="ddlFileType_0" class="upload-Dropdowns">
            <option value="0">--Select--</option>
            <option value="1">A</option>
            <option value="2">B</option>
        </select></td>
    <td>
        <input id="txtReferenceNo_0" type="text" class="upload-TextBoxes" /></td>
    <td>
        <input id="fileDocument_0" class="file-upload" type="file" /></td>
</tr>
```

+ Add Another

I want to make a copy of second row each time on add another button.So I  have used

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addAnother").click(function () {
        addAnotherRow();
    });
});

function addAnotherRow() {
    var row = $("#tblDoc tr:nth-child(2)").clone();
    $('#tblDoc').append(row);
}
```

When I clone it give same id for second row.
I want second row with id:
1 - uploadrow_1
2 - ddlDocumentDescription_1 (Its a asp.net control so id will not look like this)
3 - txtCustomFileName_1
4 - ddlFileType_1
5 - txtReferenceNo_1
6 - fileDocument_1
and so on.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you can change the attributes of element before appending it in DOM..

Comment: @RayonDabre Like  $("#tblDoc tr:nth-child(2)") .clone().attr('id', 'id' +Count++) ? Where count is a global variable. But how can I do with inner elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/y7q6x4so/3/

Select the last row and add id incrementing by one all the time.

```
    function addAnotherRow() {
        var row = $("#tblDoc tr").last().clone();
        var oldId = Number(row.attr('id').slice(-1));
        var id = 1 + oldId;


        row.attr('id', 'uploadrow_' + id );
        row.find('#txtCustomFileName_' + oldId).attr('id', 'txtCustomFileName_' + id);
        row.find('#ddlDocumentDescription_' + oldId).attr('id', 'ddlDocumentDescription_' + id);
        row.find('#ddlFileType_' + oldId).attr('id', 'ddlFileType_' + id);
        row.find('#txtReferenceNo_' + oldId).attr('id', 'txtReferenceNo_' + id);
        row.find('#fileDocument_' + oldId).attr('id', 'fileDocument_' + id);

        $('#tblDoc').append(row);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Is your Jsfiddle is working fine? I have opened the firebug and found each text box,dropdown etc have same id.But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

- Keep a variable holding initial value as `0`
- Increment the variable inside a function which acts as a click handler.
- Reset `value` property of the `input` and `select` elements so that it is different than the one user has entered/selected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addAnother").click(function() {
    addAnotherRow();
  });
});
var counter = 0;

function addAnotherRow() {
  ++counter;
  var row = $("#tblDoc tr:nth-child(2)").clone();
  row.find('input').val('');
  row.find('select').val('0');
  row.find(":input").attr("id", function() {
    var currId = $(this).attr("id");
    return currId.replaceAt(currId.length - 1, counter);
  });
  $('#tblDoc').append(row);
}
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, character) {
  return this.substr(0, index) + character;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblDoc" class="doc-Table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>Document Description</label></td>
    <td>
      <label>Custom</label></td>
    <td>
      <label>File Type</label></td>
    <td>
      <label>Ref</label></td>
    <td>
      <label>Document</label></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="uploadrow_0">
    <td>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDocumentDescription_0" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="txtCustomFileName_0" type="text" class="upload-TextBoxes" /></td>
    <td>
      <select id="ddlFileType_0" class="upload-Dropdowns">
        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="txtReferenceNo_0" type="text" class="upload-TextBoxes" /></td>
    <td>
      <input id="fileDocument_0" class="file-upload" type="file" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="addAnother">Add Another</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull if you clone a row containing input field with "id" and "name". If you don't handle the cloned "name" attribut (no different names) as you handle the "id", a radio button element will be created and your code will show a strange behaviour

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical use-case when template literals shine. We can create a function that returns a template literal and which can be parameterized with the values passed to the function, then create a click event and an ever-incrementing index.

```js
function getRow(i) {
    return `<tr id="uploadrow_${i}">
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDocumentDescription_${i}" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="txtCustomFileName_${i}" type="text" class="upload-TextBoxes" /></td>
    <td>
        <select id="ddlFileType_${i}" class="upload-Dropdowns">
            <option value="0">--Select--</option>
            <option value="1">A</option>
            <option value="2">B</option>
        </select></td>
    <td>
        <input id="txtReferenceNo_${i}" type="text" class="upload-TextBoxes" /></td>
    <td>
        <input id="fileDocument_${i}" class="file-upload" type="file" /></td>
    </tr>`;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    let i = 1;
    $("#addAnother").click(function () {
        $("#tblDoc").append(getRow(i++));
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="addAnother" value="add another">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblDoc" class="doc-Table">
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Document Description</label></td>
    <td>
        <label>Custom</label></td>
    <td>
        <label>File Type</label></td>
    <td>
        <label>Ref</label></td>
    <td>
        <label>Document</label></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr id="uploadrow_0">
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDocumentDescription_0" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="txtCustomFileName_0" type="text" class="upload-TextBoxes" /></td>
    <td>
        <select id="ddlFileType_0" class="upload-Dropdowns">
            <option value="0">--Select--</option>
            <option value="1">A</option>
            <option value="2">B</option>
        </select></td>
    <td>
        <input id="txtReferenceNo_0" type="text" class="upload-TextBoxes" /></td>
    <td>
        <input id="fileDocument_0" class="file-upload" type="file" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```